# Angular4 serverside-rendering on google-app-engine standard

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, server-side-rendering

Has anybody successfully deployed an angular4 app with serverside-rendering on google-app-engine standard?

The closest I have seen so far is this github repo for app-engine-flex: https://github.com/robwormald/ng-universal-demo

Thank you!